# Multi field text and keyword fields in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I'm looking into switching from solr to elasticsearch and have indexed a bunch of documents into it without providing a schema/mapping and a lot of the fields that i would have previously set as indexed strings in solr have been set as both [text](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/text.html) and [keyword](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html) fields using [multi-fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html).

Is there any benifit to having a [keyword](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html) field also as a [text](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/text.html) field using [multi-fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html)? in my case most values in fields are single words so i'd imagine it wouldn't matter if they are sent to the analyzer but the es docs seem to imply that [keyword](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html) fields are not considered when searching or at least treated differently?

Just to expand on that a little further if i search for the term "ipad" would a document score higher if it had "ipad" in a keyword field as well as some other text field vs the same document without the keyword field? and if say "ipad" was only in a keyword field would the document still match?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer my own question i created a quick test, pretty much keyword and text fields are equivalent when searching and multi-fields seem to get the same score as their primary type so i guess the second field has no effect on search scoring

Weirdly a multi word value in both keyword and text fields got the same score which i would have expecting the keyword field to score lower or not at all but for my purposes that is fine so i'm not going to investigate it further.

## Index Creation

```
PUT test_index
{
    "settings" : {
        "number_of_shards" : 1
    },
    "mappings" : {
        "test_type" : {
            "properties" : {
                "multifield": {
                  "type": "text",
                  "fields": {
                     "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                     }
                  }
                },

                "keywordfield": {
                  "type": "keyword"
                },

                "textfield": {
                  "type": "text"
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

## Data Insert

```
POST /_bulk
{ "update": { "_index": "test_index", "_type": "test_type", "_id": 1 }
{ "doc" : { "multifield" : "ipad"  }, "doc_as_upsert" : true }
{ "update": { "_index": "test_index", "_type": "test_type", "_id": 2 }
{ "doc" : { "keywordfield" : "ipad"  }, "doc_as_upsert" : true }
{ "update": { "_index": "test_index", "_type": "test_type", "_id": 3 }
{ "doc" : { "keywordfield" : "a green ipad"  }, "doc_as_upsert" : true }
{ "update": { "_index": "test_index", "_type": "test_type", "_id": 4 }
{ "doc" : { "textfield" : "a yellow ipad"  }, "doc_as_upsert" : true }
{ "update": { "_index": "test_index", "_type": "test_type", "_id": 5 }
{ "doc" : { "keywordfield" : "ipad", "textfield" : "ipad"  }, "doc_as_upsert" : true }
{ "update": { "_index": "test_index", "_type": "test_type", "_id": 6 }
{ "doc" : { "keywordfield" : "unrelated", "textfield" : "hopefully this wont show up"  }, "doc_as_upsert" : true }
{ "update": { "_index": "test_index", "_type": "test_type", "_id": 7 }
{ "doc" : { "textfield" : "ipad"  }, "doc_as_upsert" : true }
```

## Results

```
GET /test_index/_search?q=ipad
{
   "took": 1,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 6,
      "max_score": 0.28122374,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "test_type",
            "_id": "5",
            "_score": 0.28122374,
            "_source": {
               "keywordfield": "ipad",
               "textfield": "ipad"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "test_type",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 0.2734406,
            "_source": {
               "multifield": "ipad"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "test_type",
            "_id": "2",
            "_score": 0.2734406,
            "_source": {
               "keywordfield": "ipad"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "test_type",
            "_id": "7",
            "_score": 0.2734406,
            "_source": {
               "textfield": "ipad"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "test_type",
            "_id": "3",
            "_score": 0.16417998,
            "_source": {
               "keywordfield": "a green ipad"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "test_type",
            "_id": "4",
            "_score": 0.16417998,
            "_source": {
               "textfield": "a yellow ipad"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```